# No suitable method found for write

Tags: java, arrays, io

Im attempting to write a previously created array to file.
This is the error im getting and I don't know how to fix it.

```
Zoo.java:341: error: no suitable method found for write(Animals)outputWriter.write(animals[p]);
                    ^

method Writer.write(int) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; Animals cannot be converted to int)

method Writer.write(char[]) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; Animals cannot be converted to char[])
method Writer.write(String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; Animals cannot be converted to String)
method BufferedWriter.write(int) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; Animals cannot be converted to int)
```

Here is the submodule:

```
public void writeAquatic() throws IOException                                                                
{                                                                                                            
    BufferedWriter outputWriter = null;                                                                      
    String fileName = "Output.txt";                                                                          
    outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));                                             
    for(int p = 0; p < animals.length; p++)                                                                  
    {                                                                                                        
        outputWriter.write(animals[p]);                                                                      
        outputWriter.newLine();                                                                              
    }                                                                                                        
    outputWriter.flush();                                                                                    
    outputWriter.close();                                                                                    
}
```

Background Info:
The array is an array of 3 objects - Aquatic Animals, Terrestrial Animals and Flying Animals - all which contain various features.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Just as the compiler is telling you, there is no such `write()` method. Are you looking for Serialization? `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()`?

Comment: Hint: `animals[p]` is what type? `write` expects a certain type and you're not passing one of those correct types to `write`

Answer (score 0):

`Animals` is a class that Java doesn't know how to convert it to `String`, `int`, or `char`.

I assume you want to write `Animals` instance data to file `Output.txt`.

In that case, you should define `toString()` method in `Animals` class, so the print function can convert the instance to string and write that to the file.

```
class Animals {
    String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Animal name : " + name;
    }
 }
```

See:
http://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method